# Cambiar el valor de un campo Enum C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

A ver ahora estoy intentado, cambiar el valor de un campo que es Enum en C#.

```
 `OrderStatus es un Enum : int { Open = 0, Process = 1, Close = 2}`
```

La tabla Order registro la orden por defecto es OrderStatus.Open:

`Order { CreateDateOrder: DatatimeNow, User_Id: con el usuario de sesion, OrderStatus: 0(es decir Open)`

Y cuando confirmo la compra quiero que el estatus pase a 1. Es decir estado (OrderStatus.Process):

```
  protected void buy_confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        Order order = new Order
        {
            CreatedDateOrder = DateTime.Parse(txtCreateOrder.Text),
            User_Id = userId,
            OrderStatus = (OrderStatus)1,
        };

        orderManager.Context.SaveChanges();
        Response.Redirect("OrderDetail.aspx");
    }`
```

No da error, pero no actualiza la BD. ¿A que es posible? Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Hay que traer el objeto,

```
` protected void buy_confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
    Order order = new Order
    {
        order.CreatedDateOrder = DateTime.Parse(txtCreateOrder.Text),
        order.User_Id = userId,
        order.OrderStatus = (OrderStatus)1,
    };

    orderManager.Context.SaveChanges();
    Response.Redirect("OrderDetail.aspx");
}`
```